# why does numrow>numcol for PCA in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have 15 data sets all with 62 points of information and im trying to do a pca analysis of them, every point in the first data set corresponds to same point in the second and third etc. However at the moment my code, see bellow, produces the meansa value over the 62 points not the 15, i have only included 3 in the code. why when i swap x and y in the array does it say 'we assume data in a is organized with numrows>numcols'. What could I do to change this? here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.mlab import PCA

x=np.zeros((62,3))
a=np.genfromtxt('1.txt').T[2] #list 62numbers
x[:,0]=a
print x[:,0]
b=np.genfromtxt('2.txt').T[2] #list 62numbers
x[:,1]=b
c=np.genfromtxt('3.txt').T[2] #list 62numbers
x[:,2]=c
results=PCA(x)
print results.mu
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PCA` function accepts an array with shape `(M,N)`, where `M` is the number of observations and `N` is the number of dimensions of the data (the number of features per observation). The error message is telling you that you do not have enough samples to perform PCA. PCA fails if `M < N` because in that case you are undersampled (covariance matrix is singular).

Comment: but if I was to do the PCA analysis one row ar a time, e.g. just for the first 15 points, then repeat it for the second 15 it would work, as 15>1. I just dont see why trying to do it for 62 instead on 1 is stopping it. or maybe i just dont understand

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do PCA "one row at a time" if each column of the row is a separate feature. You would still have `M < N` (1 < 15). If you are saying that you now have 15 observations with just 1 feature, then there's no point in doing PCA anyway (if you only have one feature, then you are dealing with scalar values and no dimensionality reduction is possible).

Comment: yeah ive figured out my problem. I needed to put in all of the features of the observations. although ive only got 4 features and 4<15 so im not sure why its working

Comment: It works because you have fewer features than observations. The problem is when you have *more* features than observations.